# SwiftUI send button tap to subview

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a few views that contain the same button with some different content. Because of this I made a `ContainerView` that houses the shared `Button` layout, and has room for a generic `ContentView`.

I want the `ContentView` to respond when the `ContainerView` button is tapped.

Using UIKit, I would hold a reference to the `ContentView` in the `ContainerView` and call a function on it when the button was hit. However, because SwiftUI has all the views as structs, the `contentView` is copied when put into the `ContainerView`'s `body`. Thus the reference and the shown `ContentView` are different & I cannot send the subview a message.

Code:

```swift
struct ContainerView: View {
    let contentView = ContentView()

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            /// When this button is tapped, I would like to send a message to the `ContentView`.
            Button(action: self.reset, label: { Text("RESET") })
            /// Unfortunately, this seemes to send a copy of the `contentView`. So I am unable to send the
            /// corrent struct a message.
            ///
            /// How can I send a subview a message from the superview?
            self.contentView
        }
    }

    func reset() {
        self.contentView.reset()
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var count: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            Text("Count: \(self.count)")
            Button(action: self.increment, label: { Text("Increment") })
        }
    }

    func increment() {
        self.count += 1
    }

    /// When this is called from the `ContainerView`, it is accessing a different ContentView 
    /// struct than is being displayed.
    func reset() {
        self.count = 0
    }
}
```

So the question is: how can I send a message to & run some code in the `ContentView` when a button in the `ContainerView` is tapped?

Comment: Have a `@State` property in one View, and pass it in as an `@Binding` to the other View. You can then change the value of the Binding value, which will then update your State value back in the first View.

Comment: So the issue is that I want the `ContentView` to dictate the implementation of the reset function, not the `ContainerView`. In this example I have a single int, but in my own project and the binding is a struct with multiple properties; each different `ContentView` will reset a different one.

Comment: You try to work with *reactive SwiftUI* into *imperative UIKit-like* way. Instead you need to modify *model* depending on which view should react and rebuild itself correspondingly.

Comment: @Asperi, right I guess my question was what is the `reactive SwiftUI` way of accomplishing this. Looks like some people gave some helpful answers below!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of trying to store a reference to the subview, why not make a binding between them? In your example, this could be by binding to the count.

```
struct ContainerView: View {
    @State private var count = 0

    var body: some View {
        // Your Button wrapping the ContentView
        ContentView(count: $count)
    }

    func reset() {
        self.count = 0
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var count: Int

    // ContentView's body
}
```

When the `ContainerView` resets the count, the binding will update the child.

EDIT: I see your comments about wanting `ContentView` to control the reset logic. What about trying to replicate some of the functionality of things like `NavigationLink`, where an `isActive:` bool is set, then reset, by the system on navigation?

In your case, you could try the following:

```
struct ContainerView: View {
    @State private var shouldReset: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        // Your Button wrapping the ContentView
        ContentView(shouldReset: $shouldReset)
    }

    func reset() {
        self.shouldReset = true
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @Binding var shouldReset: Bool {
        didSet {
            if shouldReset {
                // Call your reset logic here
            }
            shouldReset = false
        }
    }

    // ContentView's body
}
```

Your `ContentView` will know the change, we'll see it as a separate "state", and then that state is reset once the action is complete.

It's probably not the ideal solution, but to me it seems to replicate a pattern shown by some first party SwiftUI components.

Comment: Ahh, didn't even think of didSet. Was trying to figure out how I turn bindings into executing some code. Thanks!

Comment: Although I love this pattern, I had the most luck using an onReceive() hook to get it the Bool to work rather than didSet. I'm not sure if the @Binding is actually "set" in a way that would make it fire?

Comment: onReceive is a good idea, too. There are definitely a few ways to solve this. You could pass a closure to the sub view. You could create an observable class that passes the call along. That's the fun part of Swift, SwiftUI, and development in general: there's never a single right way to do some of these things.